# convert a matrix to change to system of linear equations and show non-trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To show $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$, a matrix named G. Then I have a vector $x$, which is unknown, how do I write $Gx=mx$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$ as a system of linear equations? I wish to convert to to linear, and not matrix. I only know there's 3 linear equations to finish it. I also can have to show if $m=7$, then there is a non-trivial solution to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that you have $$G=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
so you can find the eigenvalues of $G$. It's easy using the equation $$\det(G-\lambda I)=0$$
where the $\lambda$'s be eigenvalues of the matrix $G$.

Note that, $$\det(G-\lambda I )=\left| \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}-\lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \right|=(\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)(\lambda-7)=0.$$
So, we have that $$\lambda_{1}=-1, \quad \lambda_{2}=1, \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_{3}=7$$

So, you can write $$[1] \quad \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=-1 \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

$$[2] \quad \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=1 \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$

$$[3] \quad \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=7 \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$
where $(x,y,z)\not=\vec{0}_{3\times 1}$ and $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

This is part of the diagonalization theory, you can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix.